# Excel to remove duplicates (like a SELECT ID, max(Monday), max(Tuesday)

Tags: excel-2010

I've got a csv from a 3rd party that is imported into Excel that I cannot figure out how take the data that looks like this so that each row is collapsed down and the blanks are gone.  In SQL I would just do a select on the fields I want and de-dupe those, then max on the others to get rid of the blanks. How would this be done in Excel?

Data:
[image]

Expected results:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assumption:
1. you only need to do this once
2. Your source data starts at A1 (the headers)
3. The list of IDs are sorted and with fixed number of rows for each ID (6 rows in your example) .

Steps:

1. Create a new worksheet
2. Fill column B with the list of unique ID (in the same order as your data), start with B1
3. Fill column A with a serial number: 0,1,2,3,4.... up to the number of unique IDs, start with A1
4. Fill in column C the following formula

   =TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,OFFSET([src worksheet]!$B$2:$O$7,A1*4,0))

   6. Then you should be able to use "TextToColumn" function to make the table you want.